# Inline constant array access in CUDA

Tags: optimization, cuda

I have some code that looks like this:

```
enum { FIRST, SECOND, THIRD, FOURTH };

__constant__ int array[] = { 1, 4, 2, 3 };
// ...
__device__ func() {
  foo[threadIdx.x] += array[FIRST];
}
```

Is there a way for the compiler to automatically convert it to:

```
__device__ func() {
  foo[threadIdx.x] += 1;
}
```

so that it doesn't need a memory access? For readability reasons, I don't want to do this manually. I need it as an array also because sometimes I'm looping over it.

Comment: You might think that the `__constant__ array[]` reference is like `const`, but in fact the `__constant__ int array[]` can in fact be [modified](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#constant) *at run time* by a `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` call, so I think in general the compiler would not attempt to make such an optimization as you are suggesting.  The code you've shown does not guarantee that `array[FIRST]` will be equal to 1 *at run time*.

Comment: The semantics of `const` and `__constant__` are "read only", not "unmodifiable". A standard example for a `volatile const` object would be a clock tick counter updated by an interrupt service routine that should only be read but no written to by application code.

Comment: `const` is effectively "unmodifiable" by user code.  `__constant__` is "unmodifiable" by device code but is "modifiable" by host code.  Nevertheless my comparison to `const` was not a particularly good one.  Comparing to a compiler macro would be better, for the purpose of optimization at compile-time.

Comment: I see. But if I add "const" to the array as well, will the compiler give me the desired optimisation?

Comment: No.  Adding `const` to the `array` definition does not prevent a `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` call from overwriting the values in `array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I do not pretend to be an expert of the `nvcc` compiler driver and I'm providing this answer on the basis of an indirect observation only.

In particular, I have done the following test:

```
#include<cuda.h>

enum { FIRST, SECOND, THIRD, FOURTH };

__constant__ int test_array[] = { 44, 4, 2, 3 };

__global__ void func(int* foo) {
    foo[threadIdx.x] += test_array[FIRST];
}

int main () {

    return 0;
}
```

I'm just using a `__global__` function instead of a `__device__` function, as in your case and I'm compiling in release mode with CUDA 5.5 for a `sm=2.1` architecture. The disassembled code is

```
MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];                   
NOP;
MOV32I R5, 0x4;                                         
S2R R0, SR_TID.X;                                       
IMAD.U32.U32 R4.CC, R0, R5, c[0x0][0x20];
MOV32I R2, 0x0;                                 R2 = bias address of constant memory
IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R5, R0, R5, c[0x0][0x24];
LDC R2, c[0x2][R2];                 Load in R2 from the constant memory
LD.E R0, [R4];
IADD R2, R0, R2;
ST.E [R4], R2;
EXIT ;
```

Notice the load from constant memory (`LDC`).

If I change the `__global__` function instruction to

```
foo[threadIdx.x] += test_array[SECOND];
```

Now the disassembled code looks like

```
MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];
NOP;
MOV32I R5, 0x4;
S2R R0, SR_TID.X;
IMAD.U32.U32 R4.CC, R0, R5, c[0x0][0x20];
MOV32I R2, 0x0;
IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R5, R0, R5, c[0x0][0x24];
LDC R2, c[0x2][R2+0x4];
LD.E R0, [R4];
IADD R2, R0, R2;
ST.E [R4], R2;
EXIT ;
```

Note that now the `LDC` instruction is loading from the bias address stored in `R2` by the `MOV32I` instruction with the `0x4` offset.

Accordingly, I think I can conclude that in general the compiler driver is not optimizing the code the way you wish.